# JSON.stringify escaping without need

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

JSON.stringify is converting my json object to the following string

> {\"2003\":{\"1\":{\"2\":[\"test\"],\"3\":[\"test2\"]}}}

When it should not be escaped. The result should be as the string quoted below

> {"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}}

Rather than use a general replace of all the escaped quotes and remove ones that could be in the input. How can I set JSON.stringify to not double escape the variables?

Comment: How is your object and the resulting JSON constructed?

Comment: How the javascript object looks like? You're doing something, the problem isn't at `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are stringifying a string, not an object:

```
var str = '{"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}}';
var obj = {"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}};

console.log( JSON.stringify(str) );  // {\"2003\":{\"1\":{\"2\":[\"test\"],\"3\":[\"test2\"]}}} 
console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) );  // {"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}}
```

Comment: Found the issue, the escaping was done by WordPress's esc_attr()

Comment: @Engineer , I don't know why this don't work well. Can you help me? I asked a question where I pasted the my code and everything. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139583/how-can-i-construct-a-post-request-body-in-react-native-not-with-a-stringified-j

Comment: This does not work.  Copy and paste your code into jsbin.com and you get this.  
"\"{\\"2003\\":{\\"1\\":{\\"2\\":[\\"test\\"],\\"3\\":[\\"test2\\"]}}}\""
"{\"2003\":{\"1\":{\"2\":[\"test\"],\"3\":[\"test2\"]}}}"

Comment: Still getting the escape chars for objects in jsbin

Answer (score 8):

Try these two examples in browser`s console:

```js
let obj = {2003:{1:{2:["test"],3:["test2"]}}};
JSON.stringify(obj);

-> "{\"2003\":{\"1\":{\"2\":[\"test\"],\"3\":[\"test2\"]}}}"
```

and

```js
let obj = {2003:{1:{2:["test"],3:["test2"]}}};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

-> {"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}}
```

In both cases the **string returned from `JSON.stringify` is valid**

**In the first case** you print **"raw" string** to console which starts and ends with double quote and all nested double quotes need to be escaped (`\"` instead of `"`). JSON validators will mark this string as **malformed JSON** but it is still parsable with `JSON.parse`

**In the second case** you print **string "interpreted" as JSON** by `console.log`. JSON validators will mark it as **valid JSON** but it is no parsable with `JSON.parse` because it is not string (no quotes around)