# How can I construct a POST request body in React Native not with a stringified json but a json?

Tags: ios, react-native, post, fetch-api

I working on replace some native-code with react native. The expected POST request (implemented in `AFNetworking`) in `Charles` should be like this:

[image: AFNetworking POST]

Code snippet:

```
NSError *err;
NSData *paramData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
NSData *paramData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];   
NSString *paramString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:paramData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *param = @{@"data":paramString};
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:URLString parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (successBlock) {
        successBlock(responseObject);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    DebugLog(@"%zd", operation.response.statusCode);
    if (failureBlock) {
        failureBlock(operation, error);
    }
}];
```

---

But the request from `Fetch API` version is like this:

[image: fetch POST]

Code snippet:

```
export default async (url, param) => {
  var result = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      'data': JSON.stringify(param) 
    })
  })
  .then(response => checkStatus(response))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(e => { throw e; });

  return result;
}
```

---

My question is how can I send a post in `fetch` exactly as in `AFNetworking`? This cost me a lot of time. Thx!!

**updated:** The main difference is the annoying slashes and their body data structure, native one is json (`data`: `paramString`), while js string.

Comment: If you want a JSON response back, is there some reason you’re sending an `Accept: text/html` request header instead? Because that’s asking the server to send you an HTML response, right? Not JSON…

Comment: No need to stringify `param` in the `body`

Comment: @Engineer, but the server api asks for this structure, as you can see in my objective-c code.

Comment: @sideshowbarker , it's nothing to do with the request, only defining the response data. And in `text/html` works well in native implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, my colleague found a solution. Request body should be constructed in this way:

```
body: 'data=' + JSON.stringify(param)
```